# Base class constructor parameter

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class:

```
    public BaseData()
    {
        var dbConnection = "BasicFinanceEntities";
        if (Session != null && Session.TestModeActive)
        {
            dbConnection = "TestConnection";
        }
        Context = new BasicFinanceEntities(dbConnection);
        Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

All by data access classes use Base class.

Eg:

```
 public class AuthenticationData : BaseData
    {
        public AuthenticationData(SessionObject session)
        {
            Session = session;
        }

    .....
```

Note, 'Session' is declared in the Base class.

All my data classes take a Session object, so that I know if the user is authenticated, his id (For last_update_user type things), as well as some security checks (Can this user see this account..).

So they take a parameter, which is the session object.

The problem is, I need my base class to know this session object - but it seems the base class has a null value for Session (which is a public declaration IN the base class, and all the child classes of Base have access to it).

It seems the base constructor fires, before any code within the child constructor.

Is there a way to get the base class to see the parameter passed into the child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your base class constructor take that session object if you need it there:

```
public BaseData(SessionObject session)
{
    Session = session;

    var dbConnection = "BasicFinanceEntities";
    if (Session != null && Session.TestModeActive)
    {
        dbConnection = "TestConnection";
    }
    Context = new BasicFinanceEntities(dbConnection);
    Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

and then invoke that constructor from your derived class constructor:

```
public class AuthenticationData : BaseData
{
    public AuthenticationData(SessionObject session) : base(session)
    {
    }
}
```